# Java Swing - JScrollPane fit Viewport width to JScrollPane width

Tags: java, swing, layout, scroll, jscrollpane

I have been trying to make the content of a `JScrollPane` shrink in width, eg. i have set the the `HorizontalScrollBarPolicy` to `NEVER`, but that just ends up in no ScrollBar appearing and the content not being dispalyed anymore.

[image]

What i expect it to look like is this:

[image]

This is my MCVE:

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel( new MigLayout( new LC().flowX().gridGapX( "20" ).fill() ) );

panel.add( new JXTitledSeparator( "Test" ), new CC().growX().spanX().wrap() );
panel.add( new JLabel( "Shrink me please!" ), new CC().minWidth( "1" ) );
panel.add( new JLabel( "Never shall anyone ever be able to shrink me." ), new CC().growX() );

final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );

final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test" );
frame.getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
frame.setVisible( true );
frame.pack();
```

I sadly have no clue how to do this, the `JViewport` of the `JScrollPane` doesn't offer any methods which might helpful, neither does the `JScrollPane` itself afaik.

Also i have already tried to achieve the same thing using `BoxLayout` and `FlowLayout` instead of `MigLayout` in order to verify that `MigLayout` isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try to set "shrink 0" as a constraint on the right column.

Comment: Still doesn't help. The right column wasn't shrinking anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `Scrollable` interface on your panel.

You would want to implement the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method to return `true`.

This will force the width of the panel to match the width of the viewport. Then each component on the panel will be sized based on the rules of the layout manager.

If you don't want to implement the `Scrollable` interface yourself then you can use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which provides method that allows you to control the scrollable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Max width for Shrink Label.
   You don't need scroll bar?
   if need to use scrollbar **as needed** from scroll pane constants

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Test" );
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add( scrollPane , BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Used border layout, and moved the pack before visible.

Comment: I only want the label to shrink when necessary, so i can't just decrease the maxWidth generally. And yes, i don't want the horizontal `ScrollBar`, i only want a vertical `ScrollBar`. And i am not sure what you mean with `Or if needed use scrollbar as needed from scroll pane constants`.

Comment: Even after editing your post, it still doesn't make sense. `HORIZONTAL_SCOLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` will display a scrollbar, but i don't want one, that is the problem. and the pack call doesn't matter, that just sizes the frame.